# Macro which creates another macro with custom name

Tags: macros, tex-core

I want to create a macro `\foo` which creates another macro which a custom name set just before the execution of `\foo` via a macro `\defcommand{myCustomName}` and saves/adds something to it just as the following pseudo-latex-code suggests. Is it possible to translate this to a working `LaTeX` example?

```
%\defcommand needs to be defined
%addtocommand needs to be defined
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
%If the command \???CustomString??? doesn't exist, create it and then add the content of #1 to it.
\addtocommand{???CustomString???}{#1}
}

Some text

\defcommand{customA}
\foo{A1} \foo{A2} \foo{A3} %should create a command named `customA` (instead of ???CustomString???) which I can use in the whole document. 

\customA %this schould print A1 A2 A3    

some text...

\defcommand{customB}
\foo{B1},\foo{B2} %now \foo should create another command named `customB`...

\customB %should print A1 A2 A3

\customA %should print B1 B2
```

Note that I don't want to use an argument of `\foo` to do this. I.e. I don't want to write `\foo{Ax}{\customA}`.

Comment: A syntax such as `\foo{A}{1}` would be preferable, unless the prefix is always one letter only.

Comment: In my use cases I would have to write lots of `foo`'s wit the same second argument. For example `\foo{A1}{\mymacroA}` `\foo{A2}{\mymacroA}` `\foo{A3}{\mymacroA}`... so in my case it would much easier to write something like `\defcommand{\mymacroA}` and then just `\foo{A1}` `\foo{A2}` `\foo{A3}`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the prefix is always one letter, then you can do it:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defcommand}[1]{\@namedef{custom#1}{}}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\@foo#1\@nil}

\def\@foo#1#2\@nil{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname custom#1\endcsname\@empty
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname custom#1\endcsname{#1#2}%
  \else
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname custom#1\endcsname{ #1#2}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\defcommand{A}
\foo{A1}\foo{A2}\foo{A355}

\defcommand{B}
\foo{B123} \foo{Ba} \foo{B3}

\show\customA
\show\customB
```

This will print on the terminal

```
> \customA=macro:
->A1 A2 A355.
l.19 \show\customA

? 
> \customB=macro:
->B123 Ba B3.
l.20 \show\customB
```

Of course this wouldn't work if one wants

```
\defcommand{ABC}
```

and `\foo{ABC1}`, because it wouldn't be possible to know what's the prefix.

If the prefix may consist of more than one letter, I suggest a different syntax:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defcommand}[1]{\@namedef{custom#1}{}}
\newcommand{\foo}[2]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname custom#1\endcsname\@empty
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname custom#1\endcsname{#1#2}%
  \else
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname custom#1\endcsname{ #1#2}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\defcommand{A}
\foo{A}{1}\foo{A}{2}\foo{A}{355}

\defcommand{ABC}
\foo{ABC}{123} \foo{ABC}{a} \foo{ABC}{3}

\show\customA
\show\customABC
```

This will print on the terminal

```
> \customA=macro:
->A1 A2 A355.
l.17 \show\customA

? 
> \customABC=macro:
->ABC123 ABCa ABC3.
l.18 \show\customABC
```

---

If the intent is to establish a macro to which subsequent calls should add, then it's a different matter.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defcommand}[1]{%
  \gdef#1{}%
  \gdef\foo@current@command{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\foo@current@command\@empty
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{#1}%
  \else
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{ #1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\defcommand{\macroA}
\foo{x} \foo{y} \foo{z}

\defcommand{\macroB}
\foo{Here}\foo{is}\foo{a}\foo{new}\foo{one}

\show\macroA
\show\macroB
```

This will print on the terminal

```
> \macroA=macro:
->x y z.
l.21 \show\macroA

? 
> \macroB=macro:
->Here is a new one.
l.22 \show\macroB
```

The trick is to define `\foo` always in terms of the same wrapper command, and to add to `\defcommand` a part that defines the wrapper command as the current macro that's initialized.

How does this last set of macros work? Let's see it in slow motion.

1. Here's `\defcommand`:

   ```
   \newcommand{\defcommand}[1]{%
     \gdef#1{}%
     \gdef\foo@current@command{#1}%
   }
   ```

   If we say `\defcommand{\mymacro}` the effect will be to initialize `\mymacro` to have empty expansion. Then the (global) definition will make `\foo@current@command` expand to `\mymacro` (not to the contents of `\mymacro`, at least at the first expansion).
2. Here's `\foo`

   ```
   \newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
     \expandafter\ifx\foo@current@command\@empty
       \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{#1}%
     \else
       \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{ #1}%
     \fi
   }
   ```

   This has some complications, so let's look at a simplified version:

   ```
   \newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
     \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{#1}%
   }
   ```

   One has to know that `\g@addto@macro` adds its second argument to the (parameterless) macro given as first argument. So, assume we have declared `\defcommand{\mymacro}` and then we do `\foo{x}`: this becomes

   ```
   \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{x}
   ```

   and now `\expandafter` comes into action, changing `\foo@current@command` to its *first level* expansion, which gives `\mymacro`, so now we have

   ```
   \g@addto@macro\mymacro{x}
   ```

   which does the desired thing.
3. The more complex definition is used to ensure that no space is added in front of the first item we add:

   ```
   \newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
     \expandafter\ifx\foo@current@command\@empty
       \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{#1}%
     \else
       \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{ #1}%
     \fi
   }
   ```

   Let's see assuming that now `\defcommand{\bar}` has just been given, so that now `\foo@current@command` expands to `\bar`, whose expansion is empty. As soon as we say `\foo{abc}\foo{def}`, TeX will transform it into

   ```
   \expandafter\ifx\foo@current@command\@empty
     \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{#1}%
   \else
     \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{ #1}%
   \fi
   \foo{def}
   ```

   The first `\expandafter` changes `\foo@current@command` into `\bar`:

   ```
   \ifx\bar\@empty
     \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{abc}%
   \else
     \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{ abc}%
   \fi
   \foo{def}
   ```

   Now `\bar` *has* empty expansion, so the "true" branch is followed:

   ```
   \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{abc}%
   \foo{def}
   ```

   and, again,

   ```
    \g@addto@macro\bar{abc}\foo{def}
   ```

   so that, now, the expansion of `\bar` will be `abc` and TeX will examine `\foo{def}`. This will do exactly the same as before, but following the "false" branch, because `\bar` is no longer empty. So we'll have

   ```
   \expandafter\g@addto@macro\foo@current@command{ def}
   ```

   that becomes

   ```
   \g@addto@macro\bar{ def}
   ```

   and the final result will be the same as if we had said

   ```
   \def\bar{abc def}
   ```

   to begin with.

Comment: I just realized that my question was not clear enough... The first character in the argument of `\foo` doesn't have to match the (last character) of the `custom` macro. I.e. 
`\defcommand{A}
\foo{one}\foo{two}\foo{three}` should add `one` `two` `three` to the macro `\A` (or `\customA`)

Comment: @student Maybe the third version is what you need.

Comment: ...but I don't really understand why this works. With my very limited `TeX` knowledge I think that: When I call `\defcommand{\macroA}`, `TeX` creates an empty macro named `\macroA` and then puts this empty content to another macro called `\foo@current@command`. When then `\foo{x}` is called, `\foo@current@command` will contain `x`. When I finaly call `\macroA` I would expect that it prints nothing. I guess that `\gdef\foo@current@command\macroA` somehow ensures that `\macroA` contains everything of `\foo@current@command` since the last call of `\defcommand` but I don't see why.

Comment: Perhaps this is because my understanding of the `\def` command is to limited... Would be nice if you could add some more explanations that I can grasp why it works.

Comment: @student I've added a longish explanation.